# Parser Limitations Python Pandas read CSV vs read XLSX

Tags: python, pandas, parsing

I came across an issue while I was trying to read some data into a pandas dataframe. The first column is text, the second is datetime and the rest of the columns are numeric. There are 12 columns in total.
I tried a few different ways to read the CSV file and I faced a ParserError regardless of my approach. An example code below:

`df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', skiprows=2, sep=',', encoding='utf-8')`

The error message below:

**"ParserError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 12 fields in line 171, saw 14"
**

My best guess is that the text column was creating an extra column based on a separated somewhere. I defined columns and different separators but nothing worked.
Eventually, I had enough and I decided to save a copy of the file as xlsx to see if the pandas.read_excel() function will have the same issue parsing, to my surprise, the pandas.read_excel() function parsed the data and created a dataframe without any issues.

The code is simple: `df = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx', skiprows=2, header=0)`

I don't understand why the xlsx file works but the csv file doesn't. Is it because the csv file uses comma as the default separator and the Python csv.Sniffer doesn't have the ability to detect the separator properly or is it something else? I am trying to understand this, if someone knows, that'll be awesome!

I've tried:

1. choosing a different encoder
2. limiting number of rows read to see if it can read any of the data, it didn't throw the column number error but all rows were coming back as NaN
3. tried different delimeters
4. a combination of the above

Comment: Without seeing sample of actual file/data, incl. around line 171 we hardly can say much.  "Saving a copy as excel" - did you open the csv in Excel, or did you save as xlsx from the software where data comes? Also, if the former, did you have to specify something during the opening to help Excel parse the data from the file? There is separator inside your field and it must be properly quoted in order for csv to wotk

Comment: Also, did you check the DF after reading the xlsx? Do you have 12 or 14 columns with some Nan/ None values at the start of columns 13-14 to fill the blank cells (based on number of cells in line 171)